# How to compile LibQxt for qt5?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, window, qt5, libqxt

I am having problems compiling LibQxt for qt 5. http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src

There are commits that says "Port Libqxt to Qt5". The project says to use configure-premake but it gives the error that there is no premake for windows but in the premake folder there is a file called premake.exe with the commit "Port LibQxt to Qt5" so i guess they added the option to compile for qt5 on windows but did not update the bash script? Anyone had any luck compiling libqxt for qt5 on windows with visual c++ 2010 and would like to share with me how?

Thanks

Comment: Is this still an open problem? Cause I didn't experience any problems building the library in windows with Qt 5. v6.0.7 from the main wiki page doesn't work, so get the lastest source from the master branch instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. 
[Building libqxt on Windows with Qt5](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/issue/7/building-libqxt-on-windows-with-qt5)
Is still open.

Comment: Looks like i'll have to stick with qt4 for a while longer.

Answer (score 0):

I'v managed to compile the tip on Windows with Qt 5.2.1. Don't know about newer Qt versions, though.